# Login error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am tring to do a Submit form for my site and I have next error

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_gv9bd2y1.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can you tell me how to fix it please?
The error apears here:
`string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: Three possibilities: `ConnectionStrings` does not exists in this context. `ConnectionStrings["constr"]` does not exists in this context or `ConnectionString` does not exists.

Comment: show the area and filename (most prolly web.config) that defines your key "constr", cos as Mouser said they are the possible problems

Comment: update your question with connection stringand name inside the web config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connection string with the name "constr" does not exist in the Web.Config file of your application.

Review the documentation at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411(v=vs.140).aspx

You should have something that looks like:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add 
      name="constr" 
      connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
      Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
      ID=userName;Password=password"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```